# Je ne lui demande pas pour quelle raison nous ne (nous) arrêterons pas chez lui

Tags: verbes, verbes-pronominaux

> Je ne lui demande pas pour quelle raison **nous ne nous arrêterons pas**
> chez lui.
>
> Je ne lui demande pas pour quelle raison **nous n’arrêterons pas** chez
> lui.

J'ai l'impression que la première phrase est correcte alors que la deuxième non. Pourtant, Antidote donne cette définition :

> **arrêter** : Ne plus avancer, ne plus aller plus loin. *Le train arrête au prochain village.*

Donc, la deuxième phrase devrait aussi être correcte, non ?

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi, la deuxième phrase n'est pas idiomatique et je n'ai jamais entendu *Le train **arrête** au prochain village*, c'est toujours *Le train **s'arrête** au prochain village*.

Il s'agit peut-être d'un québécisme voulant éviter *Le train **[stop](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8366697)pe** au prochain village*.

Comment: Le dico montre la différence entre s'arrêter et arrêter. Sur les autres forums, on demande aux participants de faire des recherches avant de poser leurs questions...

Comment: @Lambie La question fait référence à Antidote qui est certainement le logiciel de correction de référence pour la langue française, et en tout cas bien plus avancé dans ses analyses qu'un simple dictionnaire. Elle est donc pour moi justifiée rien que pour ça. D'autre part, si tu trouves que la question mérite d'être fermée, un commentaire à une réponse n'est pas le bon endroit pour le signifier. Si tu veux, vote pour qu'elle soit fermée et on verra si d'autres utilisateurs partagent ton avis.

Comment: Sur [cnrtl](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arr%C3%AAter), il est écrit : _Cesser d'avancer, faire une halte, une station : 24. Arrivés près du mont où naquit saint François, un moment l'on **arrête** pour laisser respirer après si longue traite les chevaux fatigués; chacun s'élance à bas du coche et me voilà debout, croisant les bras, de long en large allant, flânant_ Donc, cette définition ressemple à celle d'Antidote. En tout cas, il semble plus sûr d'employer _nous arrêterons_ dans ma phrase. // Antidote est aussi un dictionnaire et un "manuel", il a 3 volets.

Comment: Aussi [larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/arrêter/5383) : **arrêter** verbe intransitif Familier 1. Cesser d'avancer, stopper, en parlant d'un véhicule ; cesser de fonctionner, en parlant d'un appareil : _Le bus arrête à Vavin.)_

Comment: Oui, on trouve de rares exemples. Ce sont pour moi plus des archaïsmes que du français familier. De plus, l'exemple donné par le Larousse est mal choisi, étant absolument indiscernable à l'oral de la version pronominale.

Comment: Une chose est sûre, en Français contemporain de France, on ne dit pas "le train arrête à Paris". On peut bien sûr deviner le sens, mais la réaction la plus spontanée serait de de se demander "le train arrête quoi ?" ou "le train arrête de faire quoi ?"

Comment: Après réflexion, on doit le plus souvent percevoir une différence entre *le bus arrête à Vavin* et *le bus s'arrête à Vavin* (gémination du *S*).